# Java server stopped listening to a port

Tags: java, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

My application listens on a port 31526 on startup. I noticed on many servers running it that suddenly with no indication it stopped listening to this port. I know for sure it used to listen to it because it doesn't start if this port is already taken by another process.

This happens on SuSE10SP3, some things I noticed:

1. the port is still occupied by the system and i can connect to it and write to it, but the data won't go into the program.
2. using jstack i see the listener thread running.
3. "sudo lsof -p  | grep LISTEN" doesn't show the port, but "sudo netstat -anp" shows it:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31525           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31526           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

i see no process is attached to it. port 31525 is also used by my application and does show up in lsof from above, but still netstat doesn't show a process for it also.

4. there are many CLOSE_WAIT connections on the server host and also two connections which are in ESTABLISHED state on the server but in FIN_WAIT1 state on the client.

Does anybody know what could lead to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: 31526 may be in the block of "ephemeral" port numbers assigned by other services. Maybe try a lower value over 1024?

Comment: Can another process "steal" a port used by another? My server started running holding this port

Comment: The netstat output and the LISTEN, CLOSE_WAIT, and ESTABLISHED port states all indicate that your program is running. As long as the clients can still connect you don't have to  worry about anomalies in system utilities.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for your response. Actually my application is not running properly at all, clients manage to establish a connection but the application doesn't process the data. Also seeing the same connection on one hand ESTABLISHED and on the other FIN_WAIT1 for a long while makes me think something is broken